# How to align image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am dynamically adding controls in my activity. simultaneously i'm adding a editbox and button, but facing some issue in image alignment.

[image]

Here is my code which ads the editText and Button and returns to the linear layout which is vertical in alignment.

```
 LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(0);

        final EditText textView = new EditText(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textView.setSingleLine(true);

        final LayoutParams lparams1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final Button button = new Button(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams1);


        if(id == R.id.new_alternate_number_button)
        {
            if(contactNumber == "")
            {
            textView.setHint("Enter contact Number");
            }
            else
            {
             textView.setText(contactNumber);
            }
            textView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE); //to popup numpad
        }
        else
        {
            if(contactEmailID == "")
            {
                textView.setHint("Enter Email ID      ");       
            }
            else
            {
                textView.setText(contactEmailID);
            }

        }
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);

        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);    
        button.setOnClickListener(deleteView);

        layout.addView(textView);
        layout.addView(button);

textView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textView.requestFocus();
                  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                  imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            }
        });

        return layout;
```

In my XML file i have declared linear layout which is vertical in alignment i.e icon should be at the end of screen and EditText should be left aligned.. also i need a space between EditText and image..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, the red icon should be at the end and edit box sould be left aligned..

Comment: I know this is not the solution for your problem. But why don't you consider using RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout? (Meanwhile, I will again have a look at your code)

Comment: Yes please, but already i m using one relative layout, over there again i need to use another... is it simple if i do using relative layout ??

Comment: Green one u leave, its in some other layout. its working fine. Below that only i have added one more layout.. in that i m aligining these controls dynamically.

Comment: @Suraj, pls. try to do some tweek on this.. if its not then i will look relative layout.. already i hv implemented.. again i need to rewrite.. try any help from ur side

Comment: Do you want EditText to left and button to extreme right? (Let me know if it helps) Try this: REPLACE THIS: final LayoutParams lparams1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); WITH THIS: final LayoutParams lparams1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: Yup suraj, its like this [----------------]  [OK]... i will try your code & update u

Comment: suraj, sure... i will update u, right now m out.. will check once i return back... pls stay in touch.. thanks lot

Comment: I have added another answer, try that as well. Hopefully that is what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Your LayoutParams is set to WRAP_CONTENT for Width instead of FILL_PARENT (or MATCH_PARENT).

A "pattern" that I use in similar cases is that even though I'm dynamically adding a new row/section, I still keep they layout in an xml file for that row, and then I dynamically inflate and find the elements by id, and bind to them.  Sort of like how we deal with List Items except in this case, you are not using a list.

By keeping the layout in the XML file, it'll be easier to prototype what you want to see, add padding etc.  And you can even use a RelativeLayout if you can't get the LinearLayout to work.  Again, you can do all of this in code, but doing layout in the XML offers more flexibility (and is simpler to deal with in my mind)

Comment: Yes, one lenier layout is in XML and dynamically i'm setting one more relative layout so that to give dynamic addition feature

Answer (score 1):

This how you can go about adding space between the Button and EditText:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0); // Adding margin to the left of your button
Button yourButton = new Button(this);
yourButton.setText("some text");
linearLayout.addView(yourButton, layoutParams);
```

The sequence of parameters in setMargins method:

```
android:layout_marginLeft
android:layout_marginTop
android:layout_marginRight
android:layout_marginBottom
```

[Know more about setMargins method here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

Now that I realize your requirements properly (at least I guess so) I have another answer for you. Keep me updated about how it helps.

You will have to specify weight for the elements. Let's say total weightSum of your layout is 8, then if you specify weight of the EditText as 7, it will take 7/8th of the total space. And set wight of the Button as 1, so it will take 1/8th of the space. I am using 8 just as an example, you can change it to any number you want, do some trial and error see what weights are suiting your needs the best.

Also, the weights are in float, so don't forget the "f" after the number, like 1f and 7f:

(Again, I am not near my dev machine so there may be some errors. But this should work.)

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 7f);
// Last parameter 6f defines weight. So yourEditText will take 7/8th of the space
linearLayout.addView(yourEditText, layoutParams);


layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
// Last parameter 6f defines weight. So yourEditText will take 1/8th of the space
linearLayout.addView(yourButton, layoutParams);
```

Let's see how this helps. :)

Comment: My apologies for late reply, hey i'm getting image like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/19/image2je.jpg/. :(... its slightly stretched... And thanks for your support.. what to do next ?

Comment: Whoa! That's cool! So what next? You want the margin between the EditText and the buttons?

Comment: Suraj, correct.. i want my red color image should look like the above green one which is aligned properly.

Comment: i am able to achieve by this ans .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729992/setting-number-of-columns-programmatically-in-tablelayout... create a file and put your row there and inflate it. :)

Comment: Now i m using tablelayout as u suggested..actually i'm setting fill_parent and Wrap_content to controls i.e editbox and buttons  in separate file, once i inflate them, ill update the view with the text to be display and add it to tableRow. but in the UI editbox is not stretching..its covering only the text width.. i need to specify the width manually, right now i'm taking screen width and adjusting, but i want it in more simpler way.. any thoughts???

Comment: Set weight as I mentioned earlier.